# Who wrote the Plumbus Owner's Manual?

Tags: rick-and-morty

*Rick and Morty* included a Plumbus Owner's Manual with their season 2 DVDs.

Was this written by Justin Roiland, Dan Harmon or the television cast, or is it merely promotional?

In other words, is it canon? (Using a noncanonical Plumbus can lead to many issues.)

[image: Plumbus Owner's Manual digital version]

Comment: yes.   It's canon.

Comment: @Oni How do you know?

Comment: It came with official DVDs.